# Error al intentar realizar una configuracion de Spring cloud gateway y Eureka server

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de un proyecto basado en una arquitectura de microservicios con Springboot 3.1.0 y he tenido la siguiente situacion:

Explico lo que hice, realice la configuracion de un api gateway para poder realizar el enrutamiento por dicha via de todos mis microservicios todo esto funciono bien si usaba la URL de mi microservicio, por ejemplo http://localhost:8080/api/v1/loyalpoints/companies/getAll si realizaba el enrutamiento de esta forma todo funcionaba bien, pero cuando lo hago haciendo uso de mi eureka server no esta funcionando muestro las configuraciones que tengo:

Configuracion de spring cloud gateway:
[image: Configuracion realizada para spring cloud gateway]

Servicios que tengo suscrito en eureka server:
[image: Imagen de eureka server y los servicios suscritos]

Como se puede observar los microservicios de search-companies-microservices y api-gateway estan suscrito.

Si es de ayuda muestro el controlador de search-companies:
[image: Controlador desarrollado en springboot de search-companies]

Esta es la configuracion de search-companies:
[image: configuracion de microservicio search-companies]

Al momento de realizar el request desde postman me sale el siguiente mensaje:
[image: Solicitud de postman al microservicio]

Estuve revisando en los logs de eureka o el microservicio en cuestion y no aparece nada que alerte de lo que este pasando. Ustedes creen que sea alguna configuracion del eureka:
[image: configuracion de spring eureka server]

Si a alguno le ha pasado como lograron resolverlo, he estado investigando y revisando pero no encuentro una solución a este problema tan particular.

Answer (score 0):

Actualizacion

Para que esto funcione correctamente debe ser agregado al archivo de configuracion la siguiente:

> spring:   cloud:
> gateway:
> discovery:
> locator:
> enabled: true
> lower-case-service-id: true

Si deseas obtener mas informacion puedes ir a este documentacion oficial de springboot: [spring cloud gateway docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/appendix.html)